# systemctl input method setting

Tags: input-languages, systemctl

I want to input Korean language on Ubuntu 18.04, electron application.

When the electron application is started on terminal by using `yarn start`, Korean language input works well via `ibus`.

But, when it is started by systemctl, Korean language input is not work.

Are there environment setting for input method of systemctl service?

The systemctl service is following.

```
[Unit]
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=my
Type=idle
WorkingDirectory=/home/my/electonapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/yarn start
Restart=always
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing a whole lot of environment variables. This is the expected result, as the "global" (system-wide) systemd .service units are meant to start background *services* and explicitly not meant for X11 applications (or anything that requires being "inside" a particular user session).

- For example, XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is now required by many graphical applications as it contains various session daemons' IPC sockets.
- IBus likely requires D-Bus, which *may* be covered by XDG_RUNTIME_DIR in "user session" environments, but may also need DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in "traditional" sessions.
- And the program itself may need to be told to use IBus through GTK_IM_MODULE or XMODIFIERS.

For starting a program on user login, first consider whether simple `~/.config/autostart/` would do the job. If you specifically need systemd functionality, check if **systemd --user** is used by your distribution (it exists in pretty much all of them except CentOS).

If you have *systemd --user* running, you can use it to start and manage your application:

1. If your distribution has a [dbus-user-session](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dbus-user-session) package, install it. Upon reboot, your $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS should change to "unix:path=/run/user/…/bus".
2. Convert your .service into a "user" unit at `~/.config/systemd/user/myapp.service`:

   ```
   [Service]
   Type=simple
   WorkingDirectory=/home/my/electonapp
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/yarn start
   Restart=always
   RestartSec=30
   ```

   There's no User=, as all your units run under your own account.

   Note that this example doesn't have an `[Install]` section, as even *systemd --user* doesn't have an apropriate .target for this yet. (It has default.target, but this actually runs *during* login, before X11 is available.) Therefore it'll need to be auto-started in a different way.
3. Change your X11 startup scripts to run the following commands:

   ```
   systemctl --user import-environment
   systemctl --user start myapp.service
   ```

   Note that many distros already call *import-environment* automatically, so usually all you need is the *start* command.

   For example, you can create a `~/.config/autostart/systemd-myapp.desktop` with:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec=systemctl --user start myapp
   ```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. This is exactly what I want to know.
I already knew use X11-application is not good on systemctl, but didn't know how avoid it.
systemd's logging and management is necessary for system.
I'm newbie, I will vote up when I can it ;)